# How to correctly initialize and extract Listbox Value - Userform VBA

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I have a Userform in which I want the user to select a word in each of two listbox and then save them in a sheet. The user can also (in theory) leave the pre-selected word. Here's the code I have written :

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate ()

With ListBox1 'This list is about the stake
    .AddItem "Essential"
    .AddItem "Important"
    .AddItem "Not interesting"
End With
'then I try to initialize the value of the stake. 
ListBox1.Value = "Important"

With ListBox2 'This is a second list, about priority
    .AddItem "Auto"
    .AddItem "Yes"
    .AddItem "No"
End With
'then I try to initialize the value of the priority
Listbox2.Value="Yes"

End Sub ()
```

But my problem is that, even though the two list seem to have been initialize correctly (correct word highlighted in the list when I run the UserForm), I can't extract the value of one of the list. When I run the following code :

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Feuil1.Cells(1,1)=Listbox1.Value
    Feuil1.Cells(1,2)=Listbox2.Value
End sub ()
```

Excel is able to extract the value of Listbox2 (Priority) : "Yes" but not the value of Listbox1 (Stake) : "Important". **And I don't get why the code would work for one but not the other!**

One more element : if I manually select a word in the list, then Excel is able to give me the value of both listbox.

Any clue?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your problem. The command button sets the values of cells a1 and b1 to the selected values in the userform's listboxes

Comment: It doesn't surprise me that you can't reproduce the problem, since it doesn't seem to make sense. And today the value Excel is unable to extract has changed and it is now listbox2 (priority) that can't be extracted. It's very frustating not to know why this doesn't work and ruin my whole (and more complexe) code/project! Thank you for trying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to get the current value of a ListBox**

Seems that the `.Value` property recognizes the correct list row, but doesn't react to the second listbox unless it gets focus or is activated manually.
So a brute (and not recommendable) work around would be to set **focus** each time you have to get the current value of the 2nd listbox, too.
(*This seems to be nerve-racking btw and ressembles to a certain extent to permanently selecting or activating cells instead of recommended direct referencing fully qualified ranges.*)

```
'...
Me.ListBox2.SetFocus
Feuil1.Cells(1, 2) = Me.ListBox2.Value
```

You are on the sure side, however using the listboxes' `.List` property.
`.ListIndex` as first argument indicates the current "row" by a zero-based index (0 equals row 1, 1 the 2nd one row, etc.); 
the 2nd argument `0` indicates the row index (i.e. column `1`; btw the only one here).

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Feuil1.Range("A1:B1") = vbNullString
With Me.ListBox1
    If .Listindex >-1 then Feuil1.Cells(1, 1) = .List(.ListIndex, 0)
End With
With Me.ListBox2
    If .Listindex >-1 then Feuil1.Cells(1, 2) = .List(.ListIndex, 0)
End With
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried the ListIndex method and it works! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works well for me.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Feuil1.Cells(1,1)=Listbox1.Value
Feuil1.Cells(1,2)=Listbox2.Value
Unload Me
End sub
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but I don't want to unload the userform since this is a part of a bigger and more complex code that still need to run afterward.